# How to Strikethrough Subtitle in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, titles, text-decorations

I wish to write a subtitle in a `beamer` presentation crossed over with a line (strike-through).  I tried the followings:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{soul}
\title{Blabla}
\subtitle{\sout{blablabla}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Also I tried

```
\subtitle{\st{blablabla}}
```

instead of `\sout` and the packages `ulem` and `soul` separately.  All of them give lots of errors, the first one of which is `Argument of \UL@word has an extra }. \begin{document}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, you are right--the answer already exists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pdfstring` used internally from `\title` for the pdfinfo can't cope with `\sout` usage. It must be excluded with `\texorpdfstring{\sout{blablabla}}{blablaba}`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{soul}
\title{Blabla}
\subtitle{\texorpdfstring{\sout{blablabla}}{blablabla}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]